# Android Studio build.gradle "commandLine" fails with user installed cli programs

Tags: android-studio, command-line, build.gradle

Android Studio's arm version is running on macOS with M1 chip (if relevant). In the project there is this task:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
    task minifyJs {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            exec {
                commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "scriptFolder\\minify.bat"
            }
        } else {
            exec {
                commandLine 'sh',  "scriptFolder/minify.bash"
            }
        }
    }
```

The build fails on the sh command:

```
SurveyV2/minify.bash: line 2: uglifyjs-folder: command not found

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'some/path/build.gradle' line: 61

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ProjectName'.
> Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

The scrip is one line and as you can see the problem is that `uglifyjs-folder` command is not found. The command is installed trough node's `npm` and `node` is installed trough `homebrew`.

- if the script is executed trough Androids terminal tab it works it
  works in macOS terminal as well.
- if the task in the gradle is commented out the build will work
- if inside commandLine I try a system command like 'ls','echo' or
  something else instead of my script it does work

I can't find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is installed and installs programs in /opt and before it was in /usr/local/ somewhere. I don't know why the Homebrew project decided to move the install directory.

It seems that Gradle is not using the same environment variables as my terminal where I have added the new Homebrew path. You can set the PATH specifically for the Gradle task using the environment property.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
    task minifyJs {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            exec {
                commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "scriptFolder\\minify.bat"
            }
        } else {
            exec {
                environment "PATH", System.getenv("PATH") + ":/path/to/cli/tool/directory"
                commandLine 'sh',  "scriptFolder/minify.bash"
            }
        }
    }
```

For me the path I added was `":/opt/homebrew/bin"`. I don't know if it is possible to make Greadle use your terminal environment with some Android Studio setting maybe that wold be a better solution.